# How can I access my documentation entries to post into answers?

Tags: support, documentation

For iOS [SpriteKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SceneKit) questions, the documentation feature seems pretty useful - for example, most questions about collision/contact detection not working in SpriteKit were fixed by directing the OP to one or two documentation posts.

Now documentation is closed, how can I access my documentation posts in 'edit' format to get the source of the entry in order to create Q&A posts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation

Comment: @yivi That's just the documentation page - I can't see any 'edit' link there.

Comment: If the post you are trying to copy was ever edited, you can access the edit history and see the raw markdown of the latest revision. Not as quick as a edit->ctrl+a->ctrl+c, but doable.

Comment: @Yivi - Thanks, but I can't see anything that gives me my source with the formatting. Hopefully SO will, before removing it, allow the authors of these posts to access it somehow.

Comment: Just vote-to-close as a duplicate of one of two canonical Q+A.  If they don't exist yet then just write them yourself.  But surely they do.

Comment: Go to the **contributions** section under the Documentation tab in your profile, find the relevant example, click on the link to that example, then at the bottom you'll see [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/5988?filter-tags=angularjs) link (like this) and you can see the source if you click on the `side-by-side markdown` button

Answer (score 4):

Visit the [Topics page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/topics) or access those from your [contributions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=contributions) tab  and find your topic, then click on the created or edited link:

[image]

Next Click on [View Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/152272?filter-tags=ios):

[image]

Next select the side-by-side markdown tab and optionally click on the Show more link:

[image]

That shows you the Markdown.

The cumbersome bit is the copy-ing as it doesn't allow you to copy all the text at once, it needs to be done by paragraph:

[image]

To make it easier, you can use the following [bookmarklet](https://www.google.com/search?q=bookmarklet) to toggle displaying only the newer version:

```
javascript:void($('.removals').toggle())
```

This allows you to select the entire text of the newer version:

[image: Select only newer version]

Answer (score 4):

This is almost entirely irrelevant now, but... I added a "show markdown" link below examples. Click that and you'll get the latest revision in its raw markdown format.

Comment: Geeze, all of a sudden documentation has become useful. Who'd have thought all you had to do was add a "show markdown" link? :P